# Hardcore data manipulation in csv using python

Tags: python, csv

Supposing that I have two csv files(logs.csv and users.csv)

**users.csv** (it's an excel sheet)

```
         A               B             C               D             E
2015-10-15 17:54    some name   email@email.com    some number    plan_1
2013-11-14 12:14    some name1  email1@email.com   some number    plan_2
2014-12-19 17:54    some name2  email2@email.com   some number    plan_3
      ...               ...           ...             ...           ...
```

**logs.csv** (it's an excel sheet)

```
         A               B             C               D             E
2011-10-05 17:54    some info   email5@email.com   some info     status_1
2011-11-06 12:14    some info1  email@email.com   some info1    status_2
2011-12-09 17:54    some info2  email2@email.com   some info2    status_3
      ...               ...           ...             ...           ...
```

The flow that I should follow:

- parse *column C* from **logs.csv** and compare with *column C* from **users.csv**;
- if i have a match for email (*if email from logs.csv is also present in users.csv*), add in columns *F*, *G*, *E* of users.csv the info from columns *A*, *D*, *E* from logs.csv from the line with the email match.
- the emails that are not found, can be thrown in a txt file.

In my example, on the second line and last line of logs.csv I can see that I have a match for the emails which are also present in users.csv at line 1 and 3 (`email@email.com` and `email2@email.com`). So, I will add to users.csv at lines 1 and 3, in F, G, E columns, the info from logs.csv, from lines 2, 3 and columns A, D, E.

The problem is that i don't have a big experience with csv data manipulation and I don't know which module should I use to have this done as fast / simple as possible ( `csv`, `petl` or `pandas` )

Any suggestions on what module should I use and which one should be the easiest to use in my case ?

What I have poorly done so far using `csv`:

```
import csv

with open('users.csv', 'rb') as users_csv, open('logs.csv', 'rb') as logs_csv, open("file3.csv", "wb") as out_file:
    logs_reader = csv.reader(users_csv, delimiter=';')
    logs_csv = csv.reader(logs_csv, delimiter=';')

    universal_writer = csv.writer(out_file)

    for logs_row in logs_reader:
        for users_row in users_csv:
            # I don't know how to get the third column and how to get the necessary lines from an email match.
```

I didn't get further because it might be easier using another module.

Comment: Is it possible that an email would be present more than once in either table?

Comment: Yes. It may be possible

Comment: What is the approach when that happens?

Comment: You say "it's an Excel sheet", but everywhere else (including the filenames) you say it's a csv; but the csv you posted doesn't seem to have any commas or tabs, and you're opening it with the delimiter `;` which makes it seem like you know it's delimited by semicolons.. and your file doesn't seem to have any semicolons either.  Eh?

Comment: @DSM: I don't think that makes his question any worst, he's still able to communicate what he was trying to achieve and what he tried. He's just trying to show what the data looks like.

Comment: @DSM when I exported the info from `phpmyadmin`, I exported those two files as csv, and when I opened them with libreoffice it gave me the supported delimiters :)

Comment: @Benjamin: what the data *actually looks like* determines what the appropriate solution is (the csv module doesn't support multiple-whitespace-delimited data, for example), and being able to copy and paste the data is part of constructing a good reproducible example.

Comment: @DSM, that's how the excel looks like. I put multiple spaces there to make it more readable. Imagine those values as being columns in an excel file and the `A,B,C..` letters as being the column names.

Comment: How large is users.csv? I would like to read through it in its entirety to create a Python dict with email as the key and data from columns E,F,G as the value.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend using a Pandas dataframe.

```
    import pandas as pd

    print "This program reads 2 csv files"
    print "Please enter the name of the users csv file without extension. Assumes *.csv"
    name_users = raw_input()
    print"the users file name is %s "%(name_log)
    print "Please enter the name of the log csv file without extension. Assumes *.csv"
    name_log = name + '.csv'
    print"the log file name is %s "%(name_log)
    df_users = pd.read_csv(name_users)
    print df_csv # prints the dataframe to the screen
    df_log = pd.read_csv(name_log)
    print df_log # prints the dataframe to the screen
```

Now to add the users into log
Watch this video on the use of pandas

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5JnMutdy6Fw